# Standalone tool equivalent to Object Spy from QTP

Tags: tools, qtp

I can use the Object Spy from QTP to get the id and name of SAP GUI controls, e.g. user name control from the logon screen:

- id: `/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME`
- name: `RSYST-BNAME`

Is there an equivalent standalone tool that can provide the same information?

Environment: SAP GUI 7.20.

Comment: qtp needs extra adins. for sap it needs sap addin. object spy wont work if the specific addins are not present.
try uia verify it might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a spy for SAP GUI in particular, there is a integrated script recorder in SAP GUI. 
You can access it via "Customize Local Layout (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>)" > "Script Recording and Playback...".

I also remember a SapGuiScriptingSpy.exe which I think came from SAP, but I don't remember where you can get it from.

Comment: thank you, it's usable but I can't see the objects properties, since it records only the id.

Comment: To get an object's properties and methods the SAP GUI automation help may be of use (it's accessible from the same menu). I know it's not very comfortable to do it that way, but still, better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source app you can get from here that works in a similiar manner:
http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com

And microsoft has a UISpy tool:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx

Comment: The mentioned tools are unable to see the client/user/password/language controls.

Comment: I know it doesn't have the 'pointer' but it should have a listing of active applications that you can expand down to to view the properties. So when you have your app running, and you run one of these, it doesn't recognize your app?

Comment: It recognizes the app, but it doesn't show anything below sap user area container.

Comment: Not sure of anything specific for sap then, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your time, it's true that this is a pretty specific area, and most of the tools I tried have no support for SAP.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what the underlying technology. For Win32 there is Spy++ that ships with Visual Studio. For applications that properly implement the MSAA api's for accessibility you can use UIAutomation, so the tool for that is UISpy which is part of the Windows SDK. For managed .net applications I cannot recommend [Hawkeye](http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/) enough.

If the application is a IE based, you can use my Control Grabber, which is open source [here](http://testingstax.codeplex.com/). It uses code from hawkeye to hook the browser control and then uses WatiN (on a 32Bit machine), to read the entire DOM and spit out code in a format that I want.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The mentioned apps are not supporting SAP GUI. Stax Control Grabber works on x64 using `corflags.exe`, so it can load `WatiN.Core.dll`.